# Fintek F81803 - GPIO Usage - Controling LEDs - Windows 10 IoT

Tags: c++, windows, iot, gpio

i want to try to use the GPIOs on a Jetway System with Fintek Chip F81803.
I already tried a few code samples but non of them works. The one who comes from jetway is a full .exe which i cant use, cause i need to put that in an other script.

I use Windows 10 IoT Enterprise.
How can i adress the GPIO so i can put them high/low? (maybe a code sample would be usefull)

Comment: Please, share some code sample or anything you have tried already. Maybe it is easy to fix one of your previous code samples.

Comment: Well the code example is a complete .exe with several dpp and obj files, can be downloaded here: http://www.jetwaycomputer.com/download/Fintek/F81803_wdt_gpio.zip under F81803_wdt_gpio\Windows\source_code\GPIO_SampleCode.   I just want to set high and low with a if - loop, thanks